# How to get incremented values and display it in jsp's input field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsp

I want to fetch incremented values from db and display in input field. When I open the jsp page then automatically increment value is fetch from db and display in input value of jsp. My Sequence and table is shown below:

```
Sequence:
CREATE SEQUENCE stock_register_serial_no_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
Table:
CREATE TABLE stock_requirement_request
(
  serial_no serial NOT NULL,
  stock_requirement_slip_no character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT stock_requirement_request_pkey PRIMARY KEY (serial_no, stock_requirement_slip_no)
);    
ALTER TABLE stock_requirement_request ALTER COLUMN stock_requirement_slip_no SET DEFAULT TO_CHAR(nextval('stock_register_serial_no_seq'::regclass),'"S"fm000000');
```

And my jsp is something like this:

```
try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bjspring", "postgres",
                    "postgres");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "select max(stock_requirement_slip_no) from stock_requirement_request";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                String numb = resultSet.getString(1);
                Integer number = Integer.valueOf(numb);

    %>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-25" style="float: center;">
                        <label for="stock_requirement_slip_no">Requirement Slip No</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="stock_requirement_slip_no"
                            name="stock_requirement_slip_no"
                            placeholder="Enter stock requirement slip no.."
                            value="<%=number + 1%>" readonly required>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Using these, I want when I will open this jsp(input screen), the auto increment value is display.

When db is `null`, then automatically display `S000001` and when `S000001` is saved then display `S000002`, `S000003` and so on.

Comment: In Sql Server -  USE SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR <Schema>.<Sequence>  will return the Next sequence value. Just assign this value to your Text box and Make it readonly if required.

Comment: It seems you want to increment on display, which might be problematic in multiuser system. Maybe you can clarify your logic, why it is needed to be displayed before being saved and how it should behave if two people open input screen at the same time? Otherwise you might increment on save and update in display upon successful save (ex: using Ajax call)

Comment: @Roshan using NEXTVAL , when i refresh page, sequence is increasing without saving in database.